# Why round(1.4999999999999999) = 2?

Tags: python, printing, floating-point, rounding

I wonder why

```
round(1.499999999999999)
1
```

and

```
round(1.4999999999999999)
2
```

And if I want to print it in python console, `1.499999999999999` printed as `1.499999999999999` and `1.4999999999999999` as `1.5`

Also for example `1 / 3` is printed as `0.3333333333333333` (with 16 digits after decimal point), is 16 digits after decimal point is maximum amount of digits or it's different how it's stored and how it's printed in python?

Comment: See http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: You might want to consider breaking this up and posting as multiple separate questions.

Comment: The fractional part of a float is always a power of two. The implementation has an algorithm for mapping a decimalized float literal to an appropriate `float` approximation.

Comment: Maybe you want to use [GMPlib](http://gmplib.org/) and [extend or embed the Python interpreter](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/index.html) ?

Answer (score 4):

From [Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations\Representation Error](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#representation-error) in [The Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html):

> Almost all machines today (November 2000) use IEEE-754 floating point arithmetic, and almost all platforms map Python floats to IEEE-754 “double precision”. 754 doubles contain 53 bits of precision, so on input the computer strives to convert 0.1 to the closest fraction it can of the form J/2**N where J is an integer containing exactly 53 bits.

It's likely that your Python implementation uses the [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) standard to represent numbers where, loosely, all numbers (except NaN and infinity) are represented as

```
x = f * 2^e
```

where `f` and `e` (you can think of them as the fractional part and the exponent) are integers.

---

In this case:

- `1.499999999999999` is [represented](https://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?decimal=049046052057057057057057057057057057057057057057057) as `0x3FF7FFFFFFFFFFFB`.

  This corresponds to 6755399441055739*2^-52
  which is exactly 1.4999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875.
- `1.4999999999999999` is [represented](https://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?decimal=049046052057057057057057057057057057057057057057057057) as `0x3FF8000000000000`.

  This corresponds to 6755399441055744*2^-52
  which is exactly 1.5.

The reason that `1.4999999999999999` is represented as 1.5 in Python is because 1.5 is the closest value that can be represented *in IEEE 754* to `1.4999999999999999`.

---

As the standard only represents a finite number of values (it effectively discretises the real number line to a fixed number of points) compromises must be made when a number that does not lie *exactly* on one of those points.

`1.499999999999999` is sandwiched between two numbers that *can* be represented in IEEE 754 - you can look at it as

- 6755399441055739*2^-52 == [1.4999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=6755399441055739*2%5E-52)
- 6755399441055739.496400372629504*2^-52 = [1.499999999999999](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1.499999999999999*2%5E52)
- 6755399441055740*2^-52 == [1.49999999999999911182158029987476766109466552734375](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=6755399441055740*2%5E-52)

6755399441055739*2^-52 is *closest* to 1.499999999999999 (note that the fractional part is smaller than 0.5, so rounding down is chosen).

Likewise, `1.4999999999999999` is sandwiched between two numbers that *can* be represented in IEEE 754 - you can look at it as

- 6755399441055743*2^-52 == [1.4999999999999997779553950749686919152736663818359375](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=6755399441055743*2%5E-52)
- 6755399441055743.5496400372629504*2^-52 = [1.4999999999999999](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1.4999999999999999+*+2%5E52)
- 6755399441055744*2^-52 == [1.5](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=6755399441055744*2%5E-52)

6755399441055744*2^-52 is *closest* to 1.4999999999999999 (note that the fractional part is greater than 0.5, so rounding up is chosen) so the IEEE 754 representation equivalent to 1.5 is chosen.

---

To answer your question, the results are

```py
round(1.499999999999999)
1
```

and

```py
round(1.4999999999999999)
2
```

because the second statement is functionally the same as

```py
round(1.5)
2
```

since `1.4999999999999999` and `1.5` are treated as identical - you can probably confirm this by doing something like

```py
1.4999999999999999 == 1.5
```

Note: I'll emphasise that this is dependent on the Python implementation that you're running implementing IEEE 754 for its floating-point numbers.

Answer (score 1):

That's because python isnt as much accurate so 1.49999999999999999999999999999 = 1.5 ---> round(1.5) = 2
read more about it there https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html if u want

for more accuratte calculation math library can help for example:
0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1...  = 1 and in python is 0.999999999999 so try
print(math.fsum([0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]))